# Ошибка Апача "The requested URL could not be retrieved"

Tags: apache, windows, xampp, php, mysql

Установил себе XAMPP. Все запустил. Открываю браузер ввожу localhost и в ответ вылетает ошибка

> `ERROR
> The requested URL could not be retrieved
> While trying to retrieve the URL: http://localhost/
> The following error was encountered:
> Connection to 127.0.0.1 Failed
> The system returned:
> (111) Connection refused
> The remote host or network may be down. Please try the request again.
> Your cache administrator is support@proton-isc.ru. 
> Generated Fri, 26 Nov 2010 10:45:12 GMT by bios.igodkb.ru (squid/2.6.STABLE17)`

В чем может быть проблема и как ее устранить? В файле host, который лежит в `windows/system32/drivers/etc/`

```
# Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Microsoft Corp.
#
# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
#
# This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each
# entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should
# be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
# The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one
# space.
#
# Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
# lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
#
# For example:
#
#      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
#       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host`

# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
```

Comment: У вас включён vpn или proxy сервер. Отключите интернет если это тоже не поможет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался. Решение вот в чем. Ставим XAMPP. Вырубаем сеть, убираем прокси. Запускаем апач и тд. Подключаемся к сети. В прокси указываем не использовать прокси для локальных адресов. И все заработало.

Comment: А сеть то зачем вырубать?

Comment: Возможно и не надо. Но уж вырубил что поделаешь то.....

Answer (score 1):

Можно просто взять и включить галочку **Bypass proxy server for local addresses**. Она как раз для этого и предназначена.

Comment: В каком месте эта галочка то? Я что то никаких галочек не наблюдаю

Comment: Это и есть та самая

>В прокси указываем **не использовать прокси для локальных адресов**